# How to elegantly terminate listening npm app started with 'npm start' in GitLab CI?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

An app gets started with `npm start` command in `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. The app is configured in such way that it listens for connections on defined port. So, the command above never stops, preventing other steps from the CI file to be executed.

I was trying to stop the server with `(timeout 30s npm start; exit 0)` command, but it returns code 1 anyway, and the pipeline fails:

```
$ (timeout 30s npm start; exit 0)
 > app-srv@1.0.0 start /builds/app/frontend_server
 > nodemon server.js
 [nodemon] 2.0.4
 [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
 [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
 [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
 [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
 listening on *:4000
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Is there a way to return code 0 and execute next step?

Comment: Does it work if you add an `&` at the end of the `npm start` command? Running `npm start &` will run the command in "detached" mode which means it will continue to run in the background, but won't block the terminal. See here for a more detailed explanation: https://bashitout.com/2013/05/18/Ampersands-on-the-command-line.html

Comment: I think it would work, however you have to kill the detached instance anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of a workaround, but does its job in my case:

```yaml
- timeout 20s npm start > npm_start.log || FAILED=true  # if it fails, the variable is set up
- grep -e 'listening on \*:4000' npm_start.log  # if 'listening...' is in the output,
                                                # it means the server started successfully;
                                                # if not, the pipeline fails at this point
- if [ "$FAILED" == "true" ]; then exit 0; fi  # variable gets checked, status 0 is ensured
```